# reading environment variables from java using Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, environment-variables

Everywhere I search, it says you can get an environment variable by using `System.getenv(str).`

It's not working for me. Here's what I am doing:
OS : Mac OS x 10.7
Java 1.6.x

If I do `export abc=/hello/` in my terminal and then `echo $abc`, it gives me the variable. If I close the terminal, reopen it again and do `echo $abc`, it's gone. To overcome this, I edited my `.bash_profile` file and inserted `export abc=/hello/`. Close the terminal, do `echo $abc` and it works. So I understood that the env variable is permanent now.

Now if in my java console app, I print `System.getenv("abc")`, it returns `null`. What am I missing?

Comment: how are you launching your java app?

Comment: the session that you are running on doesn't have the new exports in `.bash_profile`, re-exec `.bash_profile` from your current session and all applications should be able to see it then.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason that you needed to put the `export` in your `.bash_profile` is that setting environment variables in a shell only persist the variables in that shell, and - since you used `export` - to *children* of that shell, or in other words, other programs launched by that shell.

If you're running your java code from Eclipse, and you launch Eclipse from a shell with your environment variables set, then your program should see the added environment variables. To launch Eclipse from the shell, you'll need to use the OS X `open` command:

```
$ open /Applications/eclipse/Eclipse.app
```

Alternately, you can set the environment variables *within* your Eclipse project, and you'll need to do this if you're not launching Eclipse from a shell with the proper environment. In the *Run Configurations* dialog, look for a tab named *Environment*. Here you'll find a table for adding environment variables that will be passed to your program.

It's better to add the environment variables to the Run Configuration since that way they'll always be available to your project. Your code doesn't actually care where the environment variables are coming from, and adding them to the project is simpler, and will work the same way on different platforms.

Of course, when you run your program *outside* Eclipse, you'll need to make sure that the same environment variables exist in the shell where you e.g. run `java`.

Comment: And if I run my app from the terminal, it will get the env variable I set in the bash_profile file? No need for Run configurations then?

Comment: @Salmanmahmood yes, if you run Eclipse from the terminal, you'll need to use the OS X `open` command, but then you should see the same env vars. I'll add to the answer

Comment: Thanks!! one last query. if i set the env variable in terminal, compile my *.java file using `javac` in terminal, then run the app in terminal using `java` command, will it pick the env variables? (without writing to .bash_profile)

Comment: any environment variables that exist in the shell when you run `java` will be available to your program. So if you set it in the shell **before** running your program, or set it in your `.bash_profile`, then run your program outside Eclipse, then you'll see the same environment variables

Comment: what should be done to get the environment variables in eclipse even if its not launched from shell?

Answer (score 3):

Eclipse does not use the system's env variables unless launched directly from the shell (which is how it is generally launched, by clicking its icon). In that case you will have to explicitly set the required env variables in the environment tab of the run configuration of the program.

Comment: On the contrary: Eclipse **will** pick up system environment variables, including any environment variables set in the shell from which Eclipse is launched on the command line

Comment: @pb2q made it explicit in the answer.

Comment: well, the answer is still misleading. Eclipse picks up env variables like any other program, which means _any_ system environment variables set e.g. for the System or User in Windows, or shell environment vars in UN*X systems.

Answer (score 0):

I too faced The same issue , I resolved it this way.

- Open Terminal
- cd to the folder where eclipse.app is located E.g `cd /Users/Shared/eclipse/jee-2020-09`
- Type `open Eclipse.app/`
- Eclipse will now open and will be able to access the system environment variables as well.

Check it using the code:

```
System.getenv().forEach((k, v) -> {
    System.out.println("ENV : " + k + ":" + v);
});
```